# break with label not bringing control to label

Tags: java

I am new to Java and preparing for OCA. I was experimenting with break and continue with label. By description in guide book it seemed both when with label, just bring the control to the label. But using test code neither it is throwing error when label for break is as earlier line nor starting the execution from label.

Though I am never going to use break and continue with label. But it important to understand it from exam point of view.

Sample code:

```
public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 0;

        label1: for(;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i==4)
                continue label1;
        }
        System.out.println("out" + i);

        i=0;
        label2: for(;i<=10;i++){
            System.out.println(i);
            if(i==4)
                break label2;
        }
        System.out.println("out" + i);
    }

}
```

Result:

```
java B
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
out11
0
1
2
3
4
out4
```

Why break is not continuing execution from label?

Also including excerpt from the guide book:

[excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdoWN.png)

My understanding from example in Yassir's answer:

label should have a block to follow.

continue brings control at the start of the block and break brings at the end. Thanks

Comment: continue and break with label make no difference from non-lable in single loop context. Use them when you have a nested loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a difference between both statements.

### [Break (JLS §14.15)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.15)

> A break statement transfers control ***out*** of an enclosing statement.

### [Continue (JLS §14.16)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.16)

> [...] Control passes to the ***loop-continuation point*** of an iteration
>   statement.

---

### Example

The following are two very simple example, not useful at all in real life, just to demonstrate the actions using different statements.

```
// This will print "continue" forever.
CONTINUE_LOOP:
while(true) {
    System.out.println("continue");
    continue CONTINUE_LOOP;
}

// This will only print "break" once and then break out of the loop
BREAK_LOOP:
while(true) {
    System.out.println("break");
    break BREAK_LOOP;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Break needs simple or nested loops. Your example is having single loop so not able to feel effect. Your example can be modified to demonstrate power of break  as follows (not using any for, while loop, need if to avoid code unreachable error):

```
public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int i = 0;
        label1:
        {
            label2:
            {
                i++;
                if(i>0)
                    break label1;
                i++;
            }
            i++;

        }
        System.out.println("out" + i);
    }

}
```

The code will print out 1 but if you change if condition to i==0 or i<1 then you will get 3 as answer. If you change break statement to break label2 then you will get 2 as answer.

> In case of continue you need label to be a loop label.

Hope it helps you in passing OCA exam.

Answer (score 0):

The break with label will cause the program to continue execution AFTER the label whereas the continue with label will cause the program to continue execution FROM the label. This is because break is for "breaking out" of a loop or label where as continue is for "continuing" execution within a loop or label but at the next loop iteration.

The following [break with label example](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Loop_Label) uses 3 loops, all nested within each other. Since there’s no way to completely break out of the outer most loop from inside the inner most loop, we can use the label `outer1` to accomplish this and specify the label next to the `break` statement.

```
outer1:
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
    for(int k=0; k<2; k++) {
      System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "][" + k + "]");
      if(j == 3) {
        break outer1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[0][0][0]
[0][0][1]
[0][1][0]
[0][1][1]
[0][2][0]
[0][2][1]
[0][3][0]
```

Notice how the last line displayed is “[0][3][0]” which is where `j == 3` and that’s where we called `break outer1;` to break out of the outer most loop.

You can also use [labels with the continue statement](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/#Loop_Label) to continue looping from a specific point. Taking the last example and just changing one line to specify `continue outer1;` instead of `break outer1;` will cause the loop to continue looping from the `outer1` label instead of breaking out of the loop. Note how each time `continue outer1` is called, the code continues from the outer loop after incrementing the loop index i by 1.

```
outer1:
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
  for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
    for(int k=0; k<2; k++) {
      System.out.println("[" + i + "][" + j + "][" + k + "]");
      if(j == 3) {
        continue outer1;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
[0][0][0]
[0][0][1]
[0][1][0]
[0][1][1]
[0][2][0]
[0][2][1]
[0][3][0] <---- CONTINUE WITH LABEL CALLED HERE
[1][0][0] <---- CONTINUES FROM NEXT ITERATION OF OUTER LOOP
[1][0][1]
[1][1][0]
[1][1][1]
[1][2][0]
[1][2][1]
[1][3][0] <---- CONTINUE WITH LABEL CALLED HERE
[2][0][0] <---- CONTINUES FROM NEXT ITERATION OF OUTER LOOP
[2][0][1]
[2][1][0]
[2][1][1]
[2][2][0]
[2][2][1]
[2][3][0] <---- CONTINUE WITH LABEL CALLED HERE
[3][0][0] <---- CONTINUES FROM NEXT ITERATION OF OUTER LOOP
[3][0][1]
[3][1][0]
[3][1][1]
[3][2][0]
[3][2][1]
[3][3][0] <---- CONTINUE WITH LABEL CALLED HERE
[4][0][0] <---- CONTINUES FROM NEXT ITERATION OF OUTER LOOP
[4][0][1]
[4][1][0]
[4][1][1]
[4][2][0]
[4][2][1]
[4][3][0]
```

Source: **[Loops in Java – Ultimate Guide](https://funnelgarden.com/java-for-loop/)**